# how too hide the top tab bar on specific screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

[I want to hide the top tab bar on this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtSK8.jpg)

[here is first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8TyY.jpg)

here is the Tab Navigator code

<Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
activeTintColor:"#000",
labelStyle:{fontSize:14},
inactiveTintColor:"#6b6e70",
indicatorStyle:{height:3,backgroundColor:'#ff007f'}
}}>
<Tab.Screen name="Wallpaper" component={WallpaperNavigator} />
<Tab.Screen name="Category" component={WallCategory} />
</Tab.Navigator>

Here is the Stack navigator code

<Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen name="Wallpaper" component={WallpaperScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
<Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={WallpaperDetail} options={{headerShown:false}} />
</Stack.Navigator>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the options={{headerShown: false}} and give it a boolean, or a condition or function that returns a boolean to hide it.
Use can detect usertap and toggle the boolean to make it feel like a full-screen mode.

Comment: akhil i want to hide the whole top tab bar not just header of bar

Comment: please guide i am unable to find any solution for that

Comment: i want to hide the whole top tab bar which is Wallpaper and category which can be seen on wallpaper screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122629/how-to-hide-tabnavigator-dynamically-on-react-native try following this thread